# emphasize.strong.rows (pander) fails

Tags: r, pander

The "emphasize.strong.rows" function fails when there are no rows to emphasize. Example:

```
#this works 
iris
iris_b <- iris[1:3, ]
emphasize.strong.rows (which(iris_b$Sepal.Width > 3))
pandoc.table(iris_b)
```

```
#this fails to work
iris
iris_b <- iris[1:3, ]
emphasize.strong.rows (which(iris_b$Sepal.Width > 4))
pandoc.table(iris_b)
```

**Error message:**
Error in apply(t, c(1, 2), function(x) gsub("[[:space:]]*$", "", x)) :
dim(X) must have a positive length

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I am trying to highlight specific rows in Rmarkdown (MS Word output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use it with an `if` condition to check if at least one row satisfies the condition.

```
library(pander)

iris_b <- iris[1:3, ]
condition <- which(iris_b$Sepal.Width > 3)
if(length(condition)) emphasize.strong.rows(condition)
pandoc.table(iris_b)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I addressed the issue using a control structure.